# NodeJS 0.4.2 http.request : can the error event be fired after the response callback has been called?

Tags: error-handling, node.js

In Node 0.4.2, is it possible for `http.request()` to return both through the callback and the error event? If, for example, a socket error occurs after the response body has been read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for http.request() to fire the error event after the response event has been fired, eg in the case that the server you are calling goes down while responding to your request.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify your question?

There does exist a generic catch-all error catcher:

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.4/api/all.html#event_uncaughtException_

Remember to stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions!

Comment: Thank you, I asked at node.js after asking here. My question used to have clarification, but someone removed half of what I originally asked.

Comment: What I actually now want to know is, when this happens, how can I handle it elegantly, ie if I've already started processing my response when the error event occurs, how can I make sure that it behaves sensibly? I imagine I'd have to remove the error listener and replace it with a different when as soon as I get the response event, but noone on node.js has been willing to say anything other than: "But that won't happen often, why bother". But it happens to me about 4 times a week, so I'd like to know...